# How to run any server that opens some port just inside Docker?

Tags: docker, networking

I have a server which is running on 0.0.0.0:[SOME_PORT]. I cannot edit port or IP it is using. Is it possible to run that in docker and expose it just via 'docker IP address' (172.X.X.X). What I need to do is run a proxy which listens to same port on localhost and redirects a call to the server. The key is that I want to run both proxy and server on same physical machine and use same port.

How I imagine the process afterwards:
endpoint my.ipaddress:port (proxy) is called -> call is redirrected to 172.X.X.X:port (docker component) -> proxy returns response from server back

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: What you describe sounds possible, with the exception that you shouldn't think about special "docker IP addresses" in most cases.  What have you already tried?